# AD Synchronization/Replication issue between 2 sites running Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

- We have an AD forest with a root domain (Main office, HQ) & 4 child domains.
- Out of which one child domain is has two sites.
- AD services are running on Windows Server 2008 R2.
- AD services in all sites were migrated from Window Server 2003, so in all AD Servers, the actual name of the SYSVOL shared folder is `SYSVOL_DFSR` and Netlogon is shared on using the same folder. NTDS DB is present in `NTDS` folder.

In the child domain that has 2 sites, one site is newly created and ADC (Windows Server 2008 R2) is installed in this server.

Now while promoting the DC in the new site, I have created SYSVOL as `SYSVOL` instead of normal `SYSVOL_DFSR` present in all other sites.

On 1st day I got few errors on the client systems regarding a domain trust relationship issue and once we restarted the client workstations, we have not received any errors again.

The problem is that AD synchronization is not working properly as in whenever I create any account or do any changes in security of any user/group in one site then it is not reflecting immediately in other site Domain controllers (same child domain) & taking 5-15 minutes times to synchronize.

What are the steps to verify proper ADC installation and to troubleshoot site to site AD replication?

Additionally, I have manually added a connection between the child domain (PDC Emulator) located in the other site. The ADC has automatically created a connection with the root domain. In AD sites and services my enterprise admin has created sites and subnets for my sites. But he has later on created a site to site bridge (not link) between these 2 sites via the root domain located in the main office (HQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD replication honors Replication Interval set on the Site Link between two sites. Which can have minimum interval of 15 minutes.
But to you can enable Change Notification for site links.

To do this:

1. Open ADSIEdit.msc.
2. In ADSI Edit, expand the Configuration container.
3. Expand Sites, navigate to the Inter-Site Transports container, and select CN=IP. 
     Note: You cannot enable change notification for SMTP links.
4. Right-click the site link object for the sites where you want to enable change notification, e.g CN=DEFAULTSITELINK, click Properties.
5. In the Attribute Editor tab, double click on options.

   a. If the Value(s) box shows , type 1

   b. If the Value(s) box contains a value, you must  derive the new value by using a Boolean BITWISE-OR calculation on the old value, as follows: old_value BITWISE-OR 1. For example, if the value in the Value(s) box is 2, calculate 0010 OR 0001 to equal 0011. Type the integer value of the result in the Edit Attribute box; for this example, the value is 3.
6. Click OK.

More info is here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/qzaidi/2010/09/23/enable-change-notifications-between-sites-how-and-why/

You can find VBScript to enable Change Notification here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/390b54d2-cd49-4f46-92e0-c22ff6f25f1c

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Just want to clarify that our Enterprise Administrator has not created 'Site to Site' link between Site A & Site B (DCs are in same domain), but created Bridge link between Site A to HQ office & HQ office to Site B. In Bridge link we are not getting 'Options' field in 'Attribute Editor'. Whether my Enterprise Administrator has made mistake by not creating site link between site A & Site B.

Comment: @GVakharia it's OK. This only makes DCs in Sites A and B to replicate via HQ Site. The solution will still work if you apply changes to site links **Site A <-> HQ** and **Site B <-> HQ**

Comment: one more thing I want to clarify. In all DCs located in site A is having DFSR Migrating SysVols entries in registry (HKLM\system\Currentcontrolset\services\DFSR\Parameters\sysvols\migratingsysvols) where as in this new DC located in site B there is no entries related to DFSR. Is it going to create any issue regarding AD replication?

Comment: @GVakharia if I understood correctly, DC in Site B was not migrated, but was newly installed. So migration never took place on Site B DC, and thus no entries in the registry about it. It should not create any problems. You might want to check for any errors in Event Log to make sure

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds like normal behaviour.  The expected behaviour re. `SYSVOL` and `SYSVOL_DFSR`is that domain controllers that are upgraded from NTFRS to DFSR will have `SYSVOL_DFSR` and domain controllers subsequently promoted will have the folder named `SYSVOL`.  This should not make any difference to replication.

The second 'issue', that changes made in Active Directory Users and Computers take ~15 minutes to become visible on other DCs is also expected behaviour to some extent.  The default inter-site replication interval is 180 minutes, but that can be configured down to 15 minutes.

Comment: As per my understanding, in same domain if user gets locked/changing password/adding user in security group get reflects/replicate/synchronize immediately irrespective of whether DCs are located at any sites. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Nope, only account lockouts (and some other things you didn't mention).  see under 'Urgent Replication' here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_repup_how_huzs